# bmake: Proper use of Automatic Variables

Tags: c, makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Werror
VPATH = ./src:./include

.MAIN: libstring.so
.PHONY: clean

libstring.o: libstring.c libstring.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -I ./include -o $@

libstring.so: libstring.o
    $(CC) -fPIC -shared $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf ./*.o ./*.so
```

In the code snippet above, I'm specifically interested in whether or not I'm using the `<` automatic variable correctly. This works if the source/prerequisite is a c source file, but seems to fail for object files.

When compiling, I receive the error:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared  -o libstring.so
gcc: No input files specified
```

Comment: FYI: if you have multiple files to be linked together, use `$^` instead.

Comment: It's just the one, but I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: This is strange... I take it that this "snippet" isn't your whole makefile. Could you post a minimal complete example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you *sure* you're using GNU make?  The code you've written will work as you expect in GNU make.  However, other versions of make do not support automatic variables in explicit rules, only in suffix (implicit) rules.  If you're using SunOS/Solaris make, for example, then `$<` will be empty on an explicit rule.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I couldn't find an option to cause my version of make to print its version information and "assumed" it to be gnu make. After some quick Googling, I guess FreeBSD uses its own version of make. I've updated the title to reflect FreeBSD's version of make.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I'cant really tell you why this happens, but I can reproduce it and I have a workaround for it that - at least - saves you half of the work.

I'm using freebsd (9.0) and have exactly the same effects with local variables, no matter if I use the shortcuts like $<, $@ (which are not recommended anymore - see manpage) or the 'long' names like ${.TARGET}. I also tried around with different positions, but it seems, allways ONE of the local vars is simple ignored.
So, if you use this statement:

```
libstring.so: libstring.o
    $(CC) -fPIC -shared libstring.o -o $@
```

everything compiles fine. I'm currently still trying around, but I guess your code is not created on a freebsd machine, so parts of the Makefile and project might come with gnu settings, that scrambles this a bit.

Regarding the 'one' I mentioned above, I have some Makefiles here, where adding a further, different variable (e.g. $^) is resulting in a work entry, too. Like this:

```
libstring.so: libstring.o
    $(CC) -fPIC -shared $< -o $@ $^
```

I'm still on it, because I'm porting a lot from linux to freebsd, so maybe I find the final point. But my guess is, it's not 'original' freebsd source, so the Makefile syntax isn't, too.

Call ***make -d A***, to see how the make command handles your local vars

greetings
jimmy

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `$^` in this case.  `$^` is the list of all prerequisites, while `$<` is the single prerequisite that has changed more recently than the target.

Answer (score -1):

I could not reproduce the phenomenon you describe.  Either your problem statement is incomplete or your version of `make` has a bug.

```
brian@hplaptop:~/src/so/mk$ echo 'int foo;' > libstring.c
brian@hplaptop:~/src/so/mk$ cat Makefile

all: libstring.so

libstring.so: libstring.o
    $(CC) -fPIC -shared $< -o $@

brian@hplaptop:~/src/so/mk$ make
cc    -c -o libstring.o libstring.c
cc -fPIC -shared libstring.o -o libstring.so
brian@hplaptop:~/src/so/mk$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```